# Laravel Middleware Redirection Error

Tags: laravel

I have two tables user and roles table with their respective Models with Many to Many Relationship. Giving them with a pivot table user_roles that contains 'user_id' and 'role_id' column

these are the files:

User.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class User extends Authenticatable {

    protected $fillable = [ 'name', 'email', 'password'];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token'
    ];

    public function setPasswordAttribute($password) {
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
    }

    public function setBirthdateAttribute($birthdate) {
        $this->attributes['birthdate'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
    }


    public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'user_roles', 'user_id', 'role_id');
    }
}
```

Role.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','user_roles','role_id','user_id');
    } 
}
```

What my Problem is with my Middleware Redirection

Here is my Middleware File
RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated {

    protected $auth;

    public function __construct(Guard $auth) {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        if ($request->user() === null) {
            return response()->view('errors.401');
        } else {
            if ($this->auth->check()) {
//     ->                  don't have any algorithm here or any idea
                switch ($auth) {
                    case '1':
                        return redirect('home');
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        return redirect('admin');
                        break;
                    default:
                        return redirect('user');
                }
            }
            return $next($request);
        }
    }

    }
```

My problem is that I need a piece of code in that commented line above that makes this one work. My approach is to Check the currently logged on user's ID, that match in the user_roles table 'role_id' column. Thanks

Comment: Can you verify that the user is always returning the role?

    $auth = Auth::user()->roles()->first();

Comment: can you post the whole error?

Comment: ErrorException in RedirectIfAuthenticated.php line 21:
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Need HELP with this, I revised my question to a more detailed one.

Comment: I finally got this one, thanks to all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your handle function with bellow edited handle function.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    if ($this->auth->check()) {
        $auth = Auth::user()->roles()->first();

        switch ($auth->role) {
            case 'Blogger':                 
                return redirect('home');
                break;
            case 'Administrator':                   
                return redirect('admin');
                break;
            default:                    
                return redirect('user');
                break;
        }
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```